# Unable to compile Qt Symbian application that uses gSOAP

Tags: qt, symbian, gsoap

I'm using [gSOAP](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html) along with Qt for Symbian.

Under the emulator, the application compiles fine, but when I change the target of the compiler to compile for the device, I get the following error.

```
WARNING: Can't find following headers in System Include Path 
<netinet\tcp.h>
```

This gets included from the `stdsoap2.h` file as follows:

```
#ifndef WITH_NOIO
# ifndef WIN32
#  ifndef PALM
#   include <sys/socket.h>
#   ifdef VXWORKS
#    include <sockLib.h>
#    include <selectLib.h>
#    ifndef _WRS_KERNEL
#     include <strings.h>
#    endif
#   else
#    ifndef SYMBIAN
#     include <strings.h>
#    endif
#   endif
#   ifdef SUN_OS
#    include <sys/stream.h>     /* SUN */
#    include <sys/socketvar.h>      /* SUN < 2.8 (?) */
#   endif
#   ifdef VXWORKS
#    ifdef _WRS_KERNEL
#     include <sys/times.h>
#    endif
#   else
#    include <sys/time.h>
#   endif
#   include <netinet/in.h>
#   ifdef OS390
#    include <netinet/tcp_var.h>
#   else
#     include <netinet/tcp.h>          /* TCP_NODELAY */
#   endif
#   include <arpa/inet.h>
#  endif
# endif
#endif
```

I'm stumped! The file cannot be found anywhere..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To finally make it work, I had to port gSOAP to use `stdapis` instead of `libc`. I removed one of the `<netinet\tcp.h>` lines and used `<sys/select.h>` instead.

You can find the ported `stdsoap2.h` file at http://pastebin.com/xnrDbfFa.

I also discovered that Symbian does not load STL by default, so all my methods that were returning `std::vector` and `std::string` are now not compiling.

Instead of opting to the `-s` flag to disable STL usage, I added the Symbian STL port to the `INCLUDEPATH` in the `.pro` file like so

```
symbian {
    INCLUDEPATH += $$EPOCROOT\epoc32\include\stdapis\stlport
    INCLUDEPATH += $$EPOCROOT\epoc32\include\stdapis\stlport\stl
}
```

And in the `soapStub.h` I had to include

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
```

Also you should modify your `typemap.dat` and add the following in order to be able to compile.

```
# Symbian specific
xsd__dateTime = | std::string
xsd__long = | long
xsd__unsignedLong = | unsigned long
xsd__int = | int
```

Otherwise the compiler will complain about

```
'soap_outdateTime' was not declared in this scope 
'soap_indateTime' was not declared in this scope
```

since under Symbian, gSOAP is built with the `WITH_LEAN` flag, hence some of the stuff are disabled (for example, no support for `time_t` serialization and no support for `LONG64`/`ULONG64` serialization) hence the required `typemap.dat` overrides above.

Finally, for future reference, here are the command line arguments that I used to generate the files:

```
wsdl2h.exe -o service.h http://myservicelocation.com/DataDisplayingWCF.svc?wsdl
```

And then:

```
soapcpp2.exe -I "C:\gsoap-2.7\gsoap\custom;C:\gsoap-2.7\gsoap\import" "service.h" -ixw
```

You might also want to setup the namespaces in the `typemap.dat` and regenerate using `wsdl2h`.

Comment: hey , thx for your answer, it has helped a lot, only i still keep getting the errors soap_outdateTime and soap_indateTime, could you post your typemap.dat file?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to that file anymore.

Comment: i followed all your instructions, but i keep getting the 'soap_outdateTime' error, any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This header is provided by the S60 SDK, and is located here:

```
%EPOCROOT%\epoc32\include\libc\netinet\tcp.h
```

In order to correctly resolve `#include <netinet\tcp.h>` therefore, your MMP file will need to contain the following line:

```
SYSTEMINCLUDE /epoc32/include/libc
```

Comment: Do you happen to know how I could write this in the .pro file? 
I tried the following but it didn't work:

INCLUDEPATH += /epoc32/include/libc

Comment: I just tested adding `INCLUDEPATH += /epoc32/include/lib` to my .pro file, ran qmake, and the generated .mmp file contains `SYSTEMINCLUDE /epoc32/include/libc`.  What version of Qt are you using?

Comment: Had to write it as follows 
 INCLUDEPATH += $$EPOCROOT\epoc32\include\libc